# Stopping Azure Connect AD, recover mail-enabled groups

Tags: azure, entra-domain-services

We have an active Office365 subscription, and yesterday I enabled Azure AD sync but now our Mail-enabled GROUPS are not being received by any client.

I uninstalled the sync-tool on my onPremesis DC but SYNC is still active in my Azure Portal. 
I want to undo everything so hopefully I have my mail back that has been send to the groups.

Comment: please run this command in your DC `Get-ADSyncScheduler` to check the sync status.

Answer (score 0):

Simply disable DirSync in the tenant, all accounts will change to "cloud only" in few hours (max 72).

Comment: Please add a source or a good explanation why this is a safe way to do this.